# trying to recursively query reddit using promises in node.js and javascript

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to figure out how to recusively query this endpoint. I can only get 100 results at a time with a max of 1000 total. So I want to collect all the results into one array and then return that 1000 collection at the end.

```
function getComments(before){
    var where = {
        sort: 'new',
        limit: 100
    };

    if ( before ) {
        where.before = before;
    }

    return reddit('/user/'+cmd.user+'/comments').listing(where)
        .then(function(data){
            logger.log('info', data);
        }).catch(function(err){
            logger.error(err);
        });
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to setup this recursive call:

```
function getAllComments(){
    var def = q.defer();

    getComments()
        .then(function(data){
            var before = data[data.length].id;
            //call getComments(before) here

        });


    return def.promise;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Return a promise in your `then` callback and then attach 8 more `then` calls recursively on the result from the `then` calls.

http://jsfiddle.net/BWNba/50/

```
function getComments(before) {
    if(typeof before === 'undefined') {
        before = 0;
    }
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.resolve([before+1,before+2,before+3]);
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getCommentsAndMergeWithPrevious( previousData, before) {
    return getComments(before).then(function(newData) {
         return previousData.concat(newData);
    });
}

function getAllComments(){
    var promise = getComments();

    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
       promise = promise.then(function(data){
            var before = data[data.length-1];
            return getCommentsAndMergeWithPrevious(data, before);
        });
    }

    return promise;   
}

getAllComments().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Results in the following being logged

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Comment: Please kill that deferred anti pattern in your code. Promises have return values use them: `getCommentsAndMergeWithPrevious` for example can just be `return getComments(before).then(function(new){ return old.concat(new); })`

Comment: Good catch :) I will update my answer within a few hours when I get some time for it.